# making a two text box required on the click of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code on my web page:

```
<form>

    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox2" />
   first: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" >
    <input type="text" />
    Last:<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

when the user clicks on the checkbox with Id= myCheckbox2 then I want the input box fname and lname to be required. I have several other checkboxes and text boxes on my page so i want to get the input box by the id. Below is what I tried:

```
<script>

    var $myCheckbox = $('#myCheckbox2'),
      $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.checkbox').change(function() {
        if ($('.inputBox').attr('required')) {
           $('.inputBox').removeAttr('required');
        } 
        else {  
           $('.inputBox').attr('required','required');
        }
    });
});


</script>
```

the above code is making all the input boxes to be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pleas try this code:

```
<form>

    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox2" />
   first: <input type="text" id="fname" class="namefamily" name="fname" >
    <input type="text" />
    Last:<input type="text" id="lname" class="namefamily" name="lname">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<script> 
   $(function(){
    $('#myCheckbox2').on('click',function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
        
            $('.namefamily').attr('required','required');
        }else{
        
            $('.namefamily').removeAttr('required');
        }
         
    });
}); 
 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use change event on the required checkbox and for adding required to your inputs you can use `$('[name=lname],[name=fname]').prop('required', $(this).is(':checked'));`

**Demo Code**:

```js
$('#myCheckbox2').change(function() {
  $('[name=lname],[name=fname]').prop('required', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox2" /> first: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
  <input type="text" /> Last:
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```